# Is this possible in a power query?

Tags: powerquery

[image]

Can I convert the original data into the format I want through Power Query? I'm not sure if it's possible with PowerQuery or if I need to implement it with VBA, so I really need your advice.

Comment: It's perfectly possible. What have you tried so far, and what specific problem are you finding?

Comment: After grouping by power query,  completed the pivot column. But since then, I have no idea what to do in order for the value to be reversed like the end result I want. What features of Power Query should I apply?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the code you've already tried, and explain the logic of what you're actually trying to achieve, a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

Assumes 4 columns in source data {Group A, Group B, Date, Value}

Basic Method [1] Group data by Date and GroupA, and add index [2] Create separate table that inverts Value, and add index [3] Join the two tables and remove original Value column [4] Remove extra columns [5] Expand [6] Pivot

Below code can be pasted into Powerquery in Home ... Advanced Editor ...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group A", type text}, {"Group B", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Group A", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Group B", Order.Ascending}}),
// Group by Date and Group A, and add Index Column
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group( #"Sorted Rows" , {"Group A","Date"}, {{"Data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}}),
//Create new table with inverted Values for each Group A Date, with index
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom.2", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList(List.Reverse(Table.Column([Data],"Value")) , Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), "Index", 1, 1)),
//Join the two tables
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.3", each Table.RemoveColumns(Table.Join([Data] , "Index", [Custom.2] , "Index", JoinSide.Left),{"Index","Value"})),
//Remove Excess Columns
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Group A", "Date", "Data", "Custom.2"}),
// Expand and pivot
#"Expanded Custom.3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom.3", {"Group A", "Group B", "Date", "Column1"}, {"Group A", "Group B", "Date", "Column1"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom.3", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom.3", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Column1", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: I checked writing too late. Thank you very much for your kind explanation.